# Reading Json file's root in c++ with jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

File:

```
{  
   "somestring":{  
      "a":1,
      "b":7,
      "c":17,
      "d":137,
      "e":"Republic"
   },
}
```

how can I read the somestring value by jsoncpp?

Comment: Basically I want to get the value of key which is "somestring"

Comment: So what problem are you having? Where is your code that tries to do this?

Comment: You can use the `getMemberNames()` method to get a vector containing all the property names. `"somestring"` will be the first element of that vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getMemberNames()` method.

```
Json::Value root;
root << jsonString;
Json::Value::Members propNames = root.getMemberNames();
std::string firstProp = propNames[0];
std::cout << firstProp << '\n'; // should print somestring
```

If you want to see all the properties, you can loop through it using an iterator:

```
for (auto it: propNames) {
    cout << "Property: " << *it << " Value: " << root[*it].asString() << "\n";
}
```

This simple loop will only work for properties whose values are strings. If you want to handle nested objects, like in your example, you'll need to make it recursive, which I'm leaving as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And how can I know how many members in my file? Like I want to use a for loop to print all names in my file.

Comment: it has a standard iterator, you can loop through all the members.

Comment: Similar to looping through a `std::vector` or `std::map`

Comment: Can u explain it with some codes? Cuz I just learn a little bit of Jsoncpp, I dont really know how it works. And I haven't learn the vector yet cuz I'm a beginner C++ student.

Comment: I've added some simple code, but you'll need to elaborate it to handle your actual object. SO is not a programming school, you need to learn how it works on your own.